# Change color of specific element with JavaScript DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to implement a paint feature in my pixel art program but the issue I am having is when I add an eventListener to the element I want to paint nothing happens. I checked tests in the console and changed the elements color in CSS and it successfully changed color. I show my code issue lower down the page of the JavaScript Code:

### JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  const height = document.querySelector('#inputHeight').value;
  const width = document.querySelector('#inputWidth').value;

  // cause the 'submit' to not reset page
  event.preventDefault();

  // When size is submitted by the user, call makeGrid()
  makeGrid(height, width);
});

function makeGrid(wid, hi) {

  // Clear the canvas after every 'submit' event
  let pixelNode = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas');
  while (pixelNode.firstChild) {
    pixelNode.removeChild(pixelNode.firstChild);
  }

  // Select size input
  let shelfWidth = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < wid; i++) {
    shelfWidth += '<td></td>';
  }

  let row = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas');
  const HTMLToAdd = '<tr>' + shelfWidth + '</tr>';
  for (let j = 0; j < hi; j++) {
    row.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', HTMLToAdd);
  }
}
```

> **Here is my issue** I see nothing wrong with my code and I dont know why this wouldn't assign each  element with the color the user chooses. The variable 'color' is a string that I am concatenating to the rest of the CSSText.

```
// Select color input
document.querySelector('td').addEventListener('click', function() {  
   // collect color value from picker to pass into paint funtion
  const color = document.querySelector('#colorPicker').value;  
  document.querySelector('td').style.CSSText = ('background-color: ' + color);
});
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="4"> 
        <br>
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="4">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
  </table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try changing `.CSSText` to `.cssText` - JavaScript is case sensitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were several issues, but the most relevant thing was that the table-cells (`td`) were empty and therefore could not be clicked respectively be painted.

```js
document.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  // cause the 'submit' to not reset page
  event.preventDefault();
  handleSubmitEvent();
});

function handleSubmitEvent(){
  const height = document.querySelector('#inputHeight').value;
  const width = document.querySelector('#inputWidth').value;
  
  // When size is submitted by the user, call makeGrid()
  makeGrid(height, width);
}

function makeGrid(wid, hi) {

  // Clear the canvas after every 'submit' event
  let pixelNode = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas');
  while (pixelNode.firstChild) {
    pixelNode.removeChild(pixelNode.firstChild);
  }

  // Select size input
  let shelfWidth = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < wid; i++) {
    shelfWidth += '<td>cell</td>';
  }

  let row = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas');
  const HTMLToAdd = '<tr>' + shelfWidth + '</tr>';
  for (let j = 0; j < hi; j++) {
    row.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', HTMLToAdd);
  }
  
  // assign a click handler to the whole table and check whether a cell was clicked
  row.addEventListener('click', function(event) {  
     // collect color value from picker to pass into paint funtion
    var cell = event.target;
    if(cell.tagName.toLowerCase()=="td"){
      const color = document.querySelector('#colorPicker').value;  
      event.target.style['background-color'] = color;
    }
  });
  
}

// draws 4x4 grid at the beginning so that you to not have to write td hardcoded
handleSubmitEvent();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="4"> 
        <br>
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="4">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

</body>
```

Hope this helps you.